# Recycling labels in for loop and releasing them

Tags: iphone, memory-management, loops, for-loop, uilabel

What's the correct way of creating an UILabel and releasing it again when I want to re-use this until i'm out of records in my array?

I wanted to this this:

```
// create label
UILabel *labelIWishToRecycle;

for (int i = 0; i < [myArrayFullOfItems count]; i++) {
    // Edit the label
    labelIWishToRecycle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 640)];
}

// Release label
[labelIWishToRecycle release];
```

When I do it this way I get a crash for releasing it. So I just don't release it. Works like a charm now. Of course, this is not the way, so I was wondering what IS.

Should I create and release the label for every item in the array? Or should I create it outside the for-loop but release it within? Or ...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what you've posted, it looks like you instantiate labelIWishToRecycle multiple times but release it only once. That would explain the crashes. If you never release it, the program will run but you'll get a leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what are you using the label!? If you are adding it to a view, than you have to use a new instance everytime.. if you only do size calculations or stuff like that, than you could use the same label over and over again.

But the trick is to initialize your local variable:
`UILabel *labelIWishToRecycle = nil;`

If you have done this, it is save to send release on it (also if no real label has been assigned yet). Before, your pointer is pointing on a random address and you are trying to release the object at that address. That will be a crash in the most cases.

(Guessing the problem case is the one, when your array count is zero.)